# Что за анонимный пользователь?

Tags: поддержка, правки, анонимный-пользователь

В правках правка была предложена каким-то анонимным пользователем. Что это за пользователь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Оригинал вопроса](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48287380#48287380)

Comment: Что за ад с цветами?

Comment: @älёxölüt вопрос не ко мне))

Comment: @älёxölüt, это плагин...  https://userstyles.org/

Comment: @AntonSorokin мотороллер не мой? :)

Comment: @älёxölüt на пикче видно что это Air, я просто разместил обьяву

Comment: ([мотороллер не мой, я просто разместил объяву](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ответ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48287765#48287765) Nicolas Chabanovsky:

> На сколько я помню, у нас можно анонимные правки делать. Думаю, это
>   одна из них. Если вы зайдете не авторизированным на сайт, у каждого
>   сообщения есть ссылка «улучшить этот вопрос».

Answer (score -1):

Анонимный пользователь - пользователь не зарегистрирован на сайте или пожелавший скрыть свои данные при ответе.